# How to get JourneyId using JobId?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm trying to get JourneyId using _Job data view, I want to query on _Journey data view but their is no direct relation in between these two data views to get only required data.
Is their any way to query on _journey data view using _job data view? I want to add JourneyId's in DE which are related to JobId or related to sent email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [Journey Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5) data view and connect it with the [Journey](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey.htm&type=5) and [Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5) data views.

This is necessary, since each you can have multiple journey activities (blocks) available in a single journey. Each of them serves like a "job" and has its own JourneyActivityObjectID that's displayed as TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID in the Sent data view.

Comment: So we have to use SQL joins to using JourneyActivityObjectID from Journey Activity and JobId from Sent data view correct ?

Comment: Yes, you need to use SQL joins based `ON JourneyActivityObjectID = TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID`. You need to either join Journey Activity with Sent or Job (or even both) depending on the data you want to retrieve.